# can't write to nfs mounted subfolder on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am on `vagrant@homestead:~$` in terminal. `vagrant` user has the groups:

```
vagrant adm cdrom sudo dip www-data ...
```

I have mounted `html` folder from a remote server having `nfs-kernel-server`. I can read all files and subfolders of the `html` folder. `html` folder has `posts` sub-folder with permissions:

```
drwxrwxr-x www-data www-data        posts
```

`vagrant` user (a member of `www-data` group) can't create files in `posts` (`www-data` group has write permission). What is the problem?

Comment: Is it mounted read-only ? `grep "\sro[\s,]" /proc/mounts`

Comment: @iamauser it says `tmpfs /sys/fs/cgroup tmpfs ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755 0 0`. But root can write.

Comment: @iamauser  I moved the question here.

Answer (score 1):

You may find that your NFS server is not honouring group access permissions. On Debian you need to enable it with the `--manage-gids` option for `rpc.mountd`. This can be done on the server by editing `/etc/default/nfs-kernel-server` and setting this option:

```
RPCMOUNTDOPTS="--manage-gids"
```

Comment: I will try this soon.

Comment: This line is already enabled. Another computer (not mine) can add files to the nfs-kernel-server. Vagrant is a virtual ubuntu in my development computer behind ADLS modem. Can this be the source of the problem?